# Humanize attributes with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I need to humanize some attributes in an app that is using MongoDB through `Mongoid`. It seems like the old way of doing things was something like

```
def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options = {})
  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
end
```

but that's been replaced with an i18n approach. Having the overrides in their own file seems like a cleaner approach. As best I can tell though, that's a product of `ActiveRecord`. Is there a way to achieve the same thing when using `Mongoid`?

Comment: Take a look at the [Translator](https://github.com/amberbit/translator) gem from Hubert Łępicki / amerbit.

Answer (score 6):

This is work for me:

```
ru:
  mongoid:
    attributes:
      part:
        name: 'Some russian word'
        content: 'Some russian word'
```